# Detecting activity revive with result

Tags: android, android-activity

My activity calls an activity in another app for result. Now, while the called activity is running, there's a chance that my process will be quietly killed for lack of memory. If that happens, once the called activity finishes, the caller activity (mine) will be revived and `onActivityResult()` will be invoked some time after `onCreate()`.

Question - in activity's `onCreate`, is there a way to tell if this is the case, or the caller activity is being invoked in the regular way?

Answer (score 0):

If the other app returns a result code, then you can check for that in the onActivityResult. If the result code is different to what you expect, then you can assume that the activity did not finish correctly, i.e it was killed.

Comment: I wanna detect it *before* `onActivityResult()`. Specifically, in `onCreate`.